# How to call C++ DLL in Delphi with string parameters?

Tags: c++, delphi

My Delphi application is calling a function from a C++ DLL that should be returning strings like this.

C++ DLL

```
__declspec( dllexport ) void sample(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    strcpy(str1, "123");
    strcpy(str2, "abc");
}
```

Delphi

```
procedure sample(Str1, Str2: pchar); cdecl; external 'cpp.dll';
var
  buf1 : Pchar;
  buf2 : Pchar;
begin
  sample(@buf1, @buf2);
  //display buf1 and buf2
  //ShowMessage(buf1); //it display random ascii characters 
end;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: It's not very clear what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate memory for the C++ code to write to. For instance:

```
var
  buf1, buf2: array [0..255] of Char;
begin
  sample(buf1, buf2);
end;
```

You should also re-design your interface to accept the length of the buffer and so allow the DLL code to avoid buffer overrun.